# CopyFromRecordSet in reverse

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I'm developing an Access database and have some code on a form button that takes the contents of a recordset and exports it to an excel document. The following code works however I have been asked that the export data be reversed on the worksheet.

```
Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("Inspection_Detail_Crosstab")
qdef![Tag_No_Param] = Tag_Number.Value
Set rs = qdef.OpenRecordset()


    EquipmentCellSt = (Col & EquipmentCell)
    With wsheet
    .Range(EquipmentCellSt).CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
```

So rather than(as it does right now):

```
 - item 1 
 - item 2
 - item 3
```

it exports:

```
 - item 3
 - item 2
 - item 1
```

I thought a method of doing this would be to:

```
With wsheet
    rs.MoveLast
    .Range(EquipmentCellSt).CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.MovePrevious
End With
```

But adding the `MoveLast` and `MovePrevious` just seems to lock up the program.

Comment: Honestly, you should reverse the output by using a query, not by modifying the VBA code. Moving around in the recordset does little to `CopyFromRecordset`, and any VBA solution will be less optimal than an SQL one.

Comment: how about sorting rows in excel after `CopyFromRecordset ` ?

Comment: Hey @ErikvonAsmuth , I have tried to amended the crostab query to order in reverse, however the records don't have an obvious way to order them such as unique keys and the values that it exports are fairly random

Comment: why are you invoking `CopyFromRecordset` for each row of the recordset?

Comment: I'm sorry @avb what do you mean? Edit: Oh i see what you mean, the loop is redundant?

Comment: your data are inserted into worksheet in certain range (mostly random as I see above), after inserting them just add a column with consecutive numbers, sort by it and then delete

Comment: You could use the `Recordset.Sort = strKeys` property and generate a sorted recordset before you call `..CopyFromRecordset rs`

Comment: Oh apologies, I did not take into account your comment about not having keys

Comment: the loop is unnecessary at all

Comment: @avb luckily, `.CopyFromRecordset` moves the recordset to `.EOF`, exiting the loop. This is also why OPs attempt with `.MovePrevious` caused an infinite loop.

Comment: @ChristopherLong I realize at some point that we must trust your understanding of the data.  However, why not show the SQL for the QueryDef [Inspection_Detail_Crosstab]... and possibly any other query on which it's based.  Although it's easy to blame "management", if they perceive a certain order and your results are opposite, then there must be some order.  I really can't imagine that there is not some order to the data which cannot be manipulated. Without the original query SQL, all of the other comments and suggested solutions are just silly guess work.  Go to the source.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually export the recordset by iterating through the records in reverse:

```
Dim rowNum as Long
Dim columnNum As Long
Dim fld As Field
columnNum = 0
rowNum = 0
'stupid client-side sorting, because management
rs.MoveLast
Do While Not rs.BOF
   For Each fld In rs.Fields
       wsheet.Range(EquipmentCellSt).Offset(rowNum, columnNum).Value = fld.Value
       columnNum = columnNum + 1
   Next
   rowNum = rowNum + 1
   columnNum = 0
   rs.MovePrevious
Loop
```

Comment: I'm quite puzzled by OP's statement that *"the records don't have an obvious way to order them such as unique keys and the values that it exports are fairly random"* - what does the order matter then? And if it *does* matter, then there *must* be a way to do this in the querydef directly. Anything but server-side sorting is a stupidly inefficient solution that will only raise eyebrows. Better add a comment, e.g. `' stupid client-side sorting, because management`

Comment: Very true, note my first comment on the question. You can do this, but you likely shouldn't. The most obvious way to fix this is to add a row identifier to the database (and it probably should have one anyway).

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes it's frustrating and in my opinion pointless, they just 'like' the rows to be sorted the other way because that's the way they used to do it, makes no different to the readability on the report.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I think you're right, I'm going to have to add some row identifiers. Unfortunately your solution resulted in the same output I have been getting with my own.

Comment: If my answer is unsatisfactory, please share your implementation of it. It should just work (albeit work slower than necessary).

Comment: @ChristopherLong the point is, they're apparently not sorted in the first place... I'd go out of my way to figure out a way to add whatever metadata is missing to make a sortable key for these records - I repeat - *whatever it takes*, to get the querydef to output its rows in the order they're needed, so no client code ever needs to do anything like this.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I have implemented you code as is, replacing my code.

Comment: @ChristopherLong Then you shouldn't get the same output as `.CopyFromRecordset`, or the same infinite loop you were getting. Please be a bit more descriptive about how it isn't working.

Comment: Sorry @ErikvonAsmuth . I have already removed the loop and removed all the code below the `Set rs = qdef.OpenRecordset()` line.

Comment: Sounds like your range might not be a valid cell. Anyway, I'm not going to remotely debug it with this little information. Just step through it and see what is happening.